# Caching in HTTP requests: ETag vs max-age

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, cache-control, etag, max-age

I have a SPA which consumes some static assets from the backend server. For reasons, I picked `ETag` validation as the caching mechanism. In short, I want the browser keep the assets in its cache forever, as long as the related `ETag`s remain unchanged.

To signal the browser about caching, header `Cache-Control` must be present in the the responses. To me it's absolutely comprehensible, but what makes me confused is that I have to provide `max-age` in the header as well. In other words `Cache-Control=public` doesn't work whereas `Cache-Control=public, max-age=100` is the correct header.

To me it sounds contradictory. The browser inquiries the server to see if an asset has changed using `If-Not-Match={ETag}` *any time* it asks for it. What's the role of `max-age` here then?

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212558/what-is-difference-between-etags-and-normal-browser-provided-caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource/file cached in browser with ETag will be anyway requested each time. If this is a `*.js` file that was changed on server then server will send a new version with a new ETag and browser will refresh it's cached version.
But anyway performed a full network round trip of request and response and this is quite expensive.
If you do expect that some file really may change at any time then you have to use ETag.

The `Cache-Control` is a directive to a browser to not even try to retrieve an updated version for some time specified by the `max-age`. This is much more performant.
This is useful for static assets that probably wont be changed e.g. `jquery-3.1.js`
file will be always the same.
Or even if the resource was changed it's not a big deal e.g. `style.css`.

During development when assets often changed the `Cache-Control` is usually disabled.

But please be careful with the `public` modifier: that means that the resource may be cached on a proxy server (like CloudFlare) and shared between different users. If the resource have private info e.g. messages then users may see data of each others.